# ESlint: Expected !== and instead saw !=

Tags: visual-studio, aspnetboilerplate

i have already tried to find eslint rules or options in the project but i could not find these.
i am using angularjs with mvc5 template type of aspnet zero.
**How to disable eqeqeq in visual studio for eslint in aspnet zero ?**

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend that you take the [tour] and read [ask]. Upon completion, you should provide us with a [mcve] to help us with answering your question.

Comment: Open Visual Studio, 
Open Tools > Options, 
Navigate to Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > EsLint, 
Set Enable ESLint to False

Comment: i dont want to disable eslint, just want to disable eqeqeq.

Answer (score 18):

The OP is asking how to disable this **One** Rule for the ***Entire*** Project.
The `eqeqeq` rule is explained here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq

### Disable One Rule at the Project Level:

To change one rule for the entire project, you should edit the `.eslintrc` file.
To find this file, you could look up the file path in Visual Studio 2017 using:
    `Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Linting`[image]
It'll probably be somewhere like: `C:\Users\<UserName>\.eslintrc`

Editing the file you will see this near the top (around Line 20):
    `"rules": {`
    `"eqeqeq": 2,`
The following are synonymous: `0` = `"off"`, `1` = `"warn"`, and `2` = `"error"`.

You may disable the rule by changing the 2nd line to this:
    `"eqeqeq": "off",`
I based this off of the information found here:
    https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

### Disable One Rule at the File Level:

Add this line in your File:
    `/*eslint-disable eqeqeq*/`
**OR**
    `/*eslint eqeqeq: "off"*/`

It is **important** you add this near the top of your Javascript file **before** your scripts.
This is because it takes affect **after** the line you add this comment to.
How to do this is buried in this link under the section "*Disabling Rules with Inline Comments*":
    https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

### Smarter is Better Than Disabling

If you're interested in changing the equality-operator warnings so they are "***smarter***" and won't *always* throw warnings (when it is obvious they do not apply), then this may be the better option.
This way you still keep these warnings when it really matters.

At the **Project** Level, use this in the `.eslintrc` file:
    `"eqeqeq": ["error", "smart"],`
**OR**
At the **File** Level, use this:
    `/*eslint eqeqeq: ["error", "smart"]*/`

This "***Smart***" feature is further explained here:
    https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq#smart

**Dislaimer:**  I have verified this works at the File Level, but have ***not*** tested at the Project Level.
    The `.eslintrc` file appears to be in Json, and these proposed edits fit the expected format.
    It also follows the examples I found in the links above.

Answer (score 3):

Add the below line to the JavaScript code to disable checking.

```
/*eslint eqeqeq: ["error", "smart"]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this file ".eslintrc" in the project's root directory and add the below code.

---

> {
> "rules": {
> "eqeqeq": "off"
> }
> }

---

Note: for more info go to this page: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules

Comment: This is already mentioned in the top-voted answer.

Comment: @aaron something similar is mentioned but is not the same.

Comment: It is exactly the same as **Disable One Rule at the Project Level**.